# Numbers related to attacks moves

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it better to have a much higher special move number or first attack number. Also do they increase when evolved or do they stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

A pokemons start attack moves will not change until you evolve it, so you should look for one with a high normal attack value and a good special attack. I prefer special attacks that take longer to get ready but have a very high attack value. When you evolve a Pokemon these attacks will change so they don't matter much. Do you expect to have a gyrados with splash? Therefore if you're planning to evolve a Pokemon, wait until you have enough candies and then pick your highest CP Pokemon, because in this game that's really all that matters.